# SharePoint modern calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Is there any way to view modern calendar by day only so it shows the time slots just like classic calendar shows when we click view by day?

Do I need to create SPFX calendar from scratch showing calendar by time just like outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **calendar view** in SharePoint online modern experience lists. The calendar view shows all the events for a day on right side panel like:

[image]

Check below articles related to calendar view in SharePoint online modern experience:

1. [Create a modern Calendar view in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)
2. [Add Modern Calendar to a SharePoint Online page using List web part](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/10/21/add-modern-calendar-to-a-sharepoint-online-page-using-list-web-part/)

---

If you are looking for more advanced & customized day view, you have to develop it using SPFx.

Check this SPFx sample [Modern Calendar](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/js-modern-calendar) which uses full calendar library to show the calendar. You can enhance it to show the [DayGrid view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view) or [TimeGrid View](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-view).

Also check other SPFx calendar samples available here which might help you: [sp-dev-fx-webparts samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts//tree/main/samples/)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh but I am looking for ‘day’ view when you select in classic calendar, it displays the all time slots on that day just like outlook.

Comment: This is not available using OOTB SharePoint functionality. So, you have to develop it using SPFx. Check my updated answer, you can enhance the "Modern Calendar" sample to show the day view using FullCalendar library.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. Links you have shared are really helpful to start  developing my custom calendar. More specifically I am looking for time grind calendar.,